# Azure Function App to pull files from other project/repo

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

Ive got a straightforward scenario but i can't figure out how to do it.

I have a SQL Database Project which has a bunch of simple SQL files and some of these drop/create summary tables.

I am trying to use a Azure Function App on a Timer to pick up certain SQL files from this project and run them ( every night ). I am however confused how to get these SQL files into my function to run?

I've tried referencing the SQL project and picking up the files from bin/debug but once function app is deployed i can see how it will be able to build the SQL Project?

Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you choose Azure Functions for achieving this, then you can utilize the REST API calls as the logic to do operations on the database either fetching or updating the data.
This approach is good for short time period.

Refer to the C# Corner [Article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/develop-a-rest-api-with-azure-functions-and-sql/) for the information and code on using the Rest APIs of database calls in Azure Functions.

I believe the long-term reliable solution for this requirement; Azure DevOps project is recommended.

1. Create Azure DevOps project for SQL Project.
2. Schedule it with an internal time which deploys the respective results at on-time whenever check-in happens on that project also.

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for more information on using the above solution.